# Сохранение в файл бинарно

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
class Data {
   char name[30];
   int age;
   Data(char name[30], int age) {
       strcpy(this->name, name);
       this->age = age;
   }
}

Дальше в main создается vector типа std::vector<Data> data;
В который в конец добавляются данные data.push_back(Data(name, age));
Нужно организовать чтения и запись этого вектора в файл бинарно. Вероятно, я что-то не так делаю, но ответы на этот вопрос на других форумах у меня почему-то не работают.
Большая просьба помочь. Спасибо.
VS 2012.
```

---

```
//чтение
ifstream infile;
long size=sizeof(data[0]);
infile.open("dat.db",ios::binary);
infile.read((char)&size,sizeof(size));
infile.read((char)&data, size);

//запись
fstream ofile("dat.db",ios::out|ios::binary); 
long size=sizeof(data[0]); 
ofile.write((char)&size,sizeof(size)); 
ofile.write((char)&data,sizeof(data));
```

Вроде бы чтение происходит нормально, а вот запись "виндовс ищет ошибки"... Проверить работоспособность чтения я не могу так как нет записи.

Comment: @miyu, а вы покажите, что именно вы делаете и как оно у вас не работает. Добавьте примеры кода сохранения в файл, которые вы пытались написать, и опишите подробнее, в чём заключается ваше "не работает".

Comment: @fori1ton, добавил код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const size_t NAME_LEN = 30;

class Data 
{
   char name_[NAME_LEN];
   int age_;

public:
    Data(const char *name, int age) 
        : age_(age)
    {
        strcpyn(name_, name, sizeof(name_));
        name_[NAME_LEN-1] = '\0';
    }

    void writeToFile(std::ofstream &file) const
    {
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&age_), sizeof(int));
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&name_), sizeof(name_));
    }
};

#include <fstream>

Data readDataObjectFromFile(std::ifstream &file)
{
    int age;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&age), sizeof(int));

    char name[NAME_LEN];
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&name), sizeof(name);

    return Data(name, age);
}

void writeVectorToFile(const char *fileName, const std::vector<Data> &arr)
{
    std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    if ( file )
    {
        size_t count = arr.size();
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&count), sizeof(size_t));
        for (auto it=arr.cbegin(); it != arr.cend(); it++)
        {
            it->writeToFile(file);
        }
        file.close();
    }
}

int restoreVectorFromFile(const char *fileName, std::vector<Data> &outArray)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    if ( file )
    { 
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&count), sizeof(size_t));
        for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
        {
            outArray.push_back( readDataObjectFromFile( file ) );
        }
        file.close();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое... все работает.

Comment: @miyu 
Круто, если так, я не пробовал это компилировать)

Answer (score 0):

Ну в общем написана какая-то муть. Вы должны определить формат хранения вектора. Например первыми 4 байтами у вас будет лежать количество элементов, а дальше последовательно их запись.
При записи вам надо будет открыть файл.

```
fstream ofile("dat.db",ios::out|ios::binary);
```

Дальше записать количество элементов вектора

```
ofile.write(&vector.size(),sizeof(int));
```

Дальше уже записать сами объекты

```
data[i].writeBinary(&ofile);
```

-

```
class Data {
   char name[30];
   int age;
   Data(char name[30], int age) {
       strcpy(this->name, name);
       this->age = age;
   }

   void writeBinnary(fstream *stream)
   {
        stream->write(age,sizeof(int));
        stream->write(name,sizeof(char)*30);
   }
}
```

Ну и запись чтение должно быть в таком же духе. Извиняюсь, если код не рабочий, писал на коленке.